# How do I run cargo flamegraph on unit-tests in lib crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a library crate which I want to profile using cargo flamegraph. But however I try to run cargo flamegraph, I get error messages. The library has the following structure:

```
utilrs
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── fileprocessor.rs
    ├── filesplit.rs
    ├── forwardstar.rs
    ├── lib.rs
    ├── persistence.rs
    └── xmlparser.rs
```

What I am looking for is to exectue a test called `split_and_process_file` within a `tests` module within the `fileprocessor.rs` file.

I tried different command line combinations, but they all resulted in errors. Some of the things I tried are:

`cargo flamegraph --unit-test -- fileprocessor::tests::split_and_process_file` resulting in `:Error: crate has no automatically selectable target`

and

`cargo flamegraph --unit-test utilrs -- fileprocessor::tests::split_and_process_file` resulting in `` error: no bin target named `utilrs`. ``

System Information:
|Component | Version|
|----------|--------|
|Operating System|Windows 10, 64-bit|
|cargo |cargo 1.65.0-nightly (4ed54cecc 2022-08-27)|
|rustc|rustc 1.65.0-nightly (84f0c3f79 2022-09-03)|

Comment: What happens if you try `cargo flamegraph --unit-test split_and_process_file`?

Comment: running `cargo flamegraph --unit-test split_and_process_file` that results in the following error: `error: no bin target named 'split_and_process_file'`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As the error indicates: `error: no bin target named 'split_and_process_file'`, there is no `bin` target.

A [target for `cargo`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html) is something like `lib`, `bin`, *etc*. That said, there is no such called `split_and_process_file`  function in your `main.rs` file.

Oops, you don't have `main.rs`, then you should create one and add your function. Then, run `flamegraph` with your `bin` files.. Don't forget to use the `--release` with `cargo run`.

As the [`flamegraph` crate page says](https://crates.io/crates/flamegraph):

> by default, `--release` profile is used,
> but you can override this: `cargo flamegraph --dev`

If you still want to use a `lib` but not a `bin`, then use the `--dev` thingy.